# Trouble with the sty file of a journal

Tags: pdftex

This is about a trouble faced concerning a particle physics journal - Journal of Physics G.
(It goes without saying that editing the sty file is hence, not an option).

When we define the title, using `\title{whatever}`, it automatically shows the title on the first page in bold font, and on each and every page as a left aligned header. Now, the problem is with symbols.

I need to type the title - `\title{\phi_s decays in context of ATLAS experiment}`. I type that and the headers appear fine, as they should. However, in the automatic bolding of the title, the words all appear in bold form, but the symbol `$\phi_s$` doesn't.

This looks ugly and is extremely undesirable, so I modify this to 
`\title{{\bf \phi_s} decays in context of ATLAS experiment}`, and now the title appears fine. But in every header, now the symbol appears in bold font and everything else is in simple font!

That's less undesirable, and that's how people have been going ahead with, but if anyone can suggest a work-around, that would be extremely valuable. I repeat that the sty file can't be edited

Comment: What's the name of the sty (or cls?) file? Is it `iopart`?

Comment: If it is for journal, ignore it or ask the journal. It is not your job as the author to decide on the typographical layout. Also remember that a bold symbol may have a different meaning (at least in some fields) so their default is sensible.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example code that reproduces the problem. I tried using a basic document of my own with [iopart.cls](http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument) but did not get bold phi symbols in the title or the running header.

Comment: @ Mico - yes it is. And your answer (given below) works very well. Thanks.

Comment: @ daleif - Thanks. Your answer bodes well with my mindset, but I've got a supervisor !! (You can guess the rest.) Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ Ian Thompson - Sir, I can't guess why you were not able to reproduce the problem. Since it is already answered, I won't bother to edit the question. I'll write the relevant part in another comment here.

Comment: @ Ian Thompson - Here it goes - \\ \documentclass[12pt]{iopart} \\ \begin{document} \\ \title{$\phi_s$ decays in context of ATLAS experiment} \\ ... (lots of stuff) ... \end{document}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using the `iopart` document class, it's actually quite straightforward to create two variants of the title -- one to be shown on the title page and the other to shown in the running header of subsequent pages:

```
\title[short title]{long title}
```

The "long title" string will be used in the title page, and "short title" string will be used in the later running headers.

In your case, specifically:

```
\title[$\phi_s$ decays in context of ATLAS experiment]%
      {$\bm{\phi}_s$ decays in context of ATLAS experiment}
```

Here, `\bm` is a macro provided by the `bm` ("bold math") package that's part of the LaTeX [tools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools) bundle.